# how to generate encrypted passwords for use with Hipster

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

I'd like to generate a series of usernames/passwords to be used with JHipster's Spring Security.  My plan was to insert these into src/main/resources/config/liquibase/users.csv but I'm having trouble generating the encrypted password to go into this file.

I expected to be able to do something like this:

```
def encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder()
println encoder.encode('admin')
```

but the produced String ("$2a$10$icbkSBY4H/ub8pKAcnYhjeCit3A6e8JszUVZfu74sG6qqrSoT9CYW") does not match the known value in the default users.csv file ($2a$10$gSAhZrxMllrbgj/kkK9UceBPpChGWJA7SYIb1Mqo.n5aNLq1/oRrC).

Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

--john

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's ok. BCrypt generates a new hash each time, because a part of this string is a random salt. Bcrypt encoder can compare such hashes, because it knows where to get *salt* and actual *hash*, so it can encrypt password using this *salt* and compare result with actual *hash*.

Your `$2a$10$icbkSBY4H/ub8pKAcnYhjeCit3A6e8JszUVZfu74sG6qqrSoT9CYW` contains:

- `icbkSBY4H/ub8pKAcnYhje` as salt
- `IjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy​` as hash

So first of all, it's ok to get different encrypted passwords each time even for same raw password. Second, you don't need to compare it manually, use `PasswordEncoder.matches`

You can also use any online BCrypt password encoder, instead of writing code for this. There're plenty of them.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt